# ArcMap VRP-StreetMap Premium-Avoid Interstates Restriction?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network-analyst, routing

Is there a way to add an "Avoid Interstates" restriction to the vehicle routing problem in ArcMap, using StreetMap Premium (HERE 2016 R2 specifically)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StreetMap Premium has a restriction called "Avoid Limited Access Roads".  When this is turned on, it will avoid all roads that are limited access highways.
Will that meet your needs?